# WinDbg not showing register values

Tags: debugging, windbg

Basically, this is the same question that was asked [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/5eeee06e-8665-43e8-abd8-8c1f5f264022/windbg-61-issue-with-registers-window-when-debugging-virtual-machine?forum=windbg).

When performing kernel debugging of a machine running Windows 7 or older, with WinDbg version 6.2 and up, the debugger doesn't show anything in the registers window. Pressing the `Customize...` button results in a message box that reads `Registers are not yet known`.

At the same time, issuing the `r` command results in perfectly valid register values being printed out.

What is the reason for this behaviour, and can it be fixed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**TL;DR**: I wrote an extension DLL that fixes the bug. Available [here](https://github.com/mbikovitsky/WingDbg).

## The Problem

To understand the problem, we first need to understand that WinDbg is basically just a frontend to Microsoft's *Windows Symbolic Debugger Engine*, implemented inside `dbgeng.dll`. Other frontends include the command-line `kd.exe` (kernel debugger) and `cdb.exe` (user-mode debugger).

The engine implements everything we expect from a debugger: working with symbol files, read and writing memory and registers, setting breakpoitns, etc. The engine then exposes all of this functionality through COM-like interfaces (they implement IUnknown but are not registered components). This allows us, for instance, to write our own debugger (like [this person](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2010/06/30/i-want-a-debugger-robot.aspx) did).

Armed with this knowledge, we can now make an educated guess as to how WinDbg obtains the values of the registers on the target machine.

The engine exposes the [`IDebugRegisters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550825(v=vs.85).aspx) interface for manipulating registers. This interface declares the [`GetValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549480(v=vs.85).aspx) method for retrieving the values of multiple registers in one go. But how does WinDbg know how many registers are there? That why we have the [`GetNumberRegisters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547960(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

So, to retrieve the values of all registers on the target, we'll have to do something like this:

1. Call `IDebugRegisters::GetNumberRegisters` to get the total number of registers.
2. Call `IDebugRegisters::GetValues` with the `Count` parameter set to the total number of registers, the `Indices` parameter set to `NULL`, and the `Start` parameter set to `0`.

One tiny problem, though: the second call fails with `E_INVALIDARG`.

Ehm, excuse me? How can it fail? Especially puzzling is the documentation for this return value:

> The value of the index of one of the registers is greater than the number of registers on the target machine.

But I just asked you how many registers there are, so how can that value be out of range? Okay, let's continue reading the docs anyway, maybe something will become clear:

> **If the return value is not S_OK, some of the registers still might have been read**. If the target was not accessible, the return type is E_UNEXPECTED and Values is unchanged; **otherwise, Values will contain partial results** and the registers that could not be read will have type DEBUG_VALUE_INVALID.

(Emphasis mine.)

Aha! So maybe the engine just couldn't read one of the registers! But which one? Turns out that the engine chokes on the `xcr0` register. From the **Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual**:

> Extended control register `XCR0` contains a state-component bitmap that specifies the user state components that software has enabled the `XSAVE` feature set to manage. If the bit corresponding to a state component is clear in `XCR0`, instructions in the `XSAVE` feature set will not operate on that state component, regardless of the value of the instruction mask.

Okay, so the register controls the operation of the `XSAVE` instruction, which saves the state of the CPU's extended features (like XMM and AVX). According to the last comment on [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/289892) page, this instruction requires some support from the operating system. Although the comment states that Windows 7 (that's what the VM I was testing on was running) does support this instruction, it seems that the issue at hand is related to the OS anyway, as when the target is Windows 8 everything works fine.

Really, it's unclear whether the bug is within the debugger engine, which reports more registers than it can retrieve values for, or within WinDbg, which refuses to show *any* values at all if the engine fails to produce *all* of them.

## The Solution

We could, of course, bite the bullet and just use an older version of WinDbg for debugging older Windows versions. But where's the challenge in that?

Instead, I present to you a [debugger extension](https://github.com/mbikovitsky/WingDbg) that solves this problem. It does so by hooking (with the help of [this library](https://github.com/nektra/Deviare-InProc)) the relevant debugger engine methods and returning `S_OK` if the only register that failed was `xcr0`. Otherwise, it propagates the failure. The extension supports runtime unload, so if you experience problems you can always disable the hooks.

That's it, have fun!

Comment: I just spent half a day trying to make the registers window work with WinDbg 10.0.17134.1 while connecting to a Win7 debuggee and failed. Your extension did not resolve the issue either. So I ended up using WinDbg v.6.12.0002.633 instead that worked like a charm! Luckily they can be both installed at the same time. The hard part was actually finding the old version of WinDbg. So to save others and myself time in the future [here it is](https://mega.nz/#!XD53iQAR!LnMWAdW9GfE5YC8aCoHq6lG6N9Fx-S7fq4MZhpAaiHU) with instructions how to install it.

Comment: @c00000fd Could you please open an issue on GitHub, describing the steps you took when using the extension?

Comment: @MichaelBikovitsky: I downloaded your [release build](https://github.com/mbikovitsky/WingDbg/releases) and then placed 64-bit version of WingDbg.dll in a folder. Then used its path in `_NT_DEBUGGER_EXTENSION_PATH` env-var & started WinDbg. Then loaded it with `.load WingDbg.dll` command. Tested that it was loaded: `.chain`. And it was. Then tried breaking into Win7 debuggee and the registers window was still empty. Tried it several times. No luck. If there are any logs that the dll generates I can send them to you. Email me if anything.

Comment: @c00000fd Did you execute the `!regfix` command after loading the extension?

Comment: @MichaelBikovitsky: No. That may be the reason why. You should probably better document it then.

Comment: Worked for me mid-debug, just loaded that dll and did !regfix